# Categorize git repositories

Tags: git, gitolite, gitweb, gitlist

I would like to organize my git repositories into categories. My main reason to do this is to get a better overview of my code repositories in the web interface I use (GitList - http://www.gitlist.org).

Now I get a long list of all the repositories, it would be nice to see only a few categories (as "repositories" or something else with description). And when you select one category you see all the repositories within that category.
I have my own git server with Gitolite (https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/) and Gitolite has some settings to categorize repositories for GitWeb, but I can't see that information in either GitWeb nor GitList, the later is not that surprising, when the setting is for GitWeb.

It would be really great to be able to categorize the repositories from Gitolite and that it showed up in GitList. But since this may not be possible (I can't see that it even works for GitWeb, where it is supposed to work) is there an other way I can manage this?

I have read some about nested git repositories, but that is not really what I am after, it does not have to affect the repositories at all, just the way that they are presented in the web interface.

Someone with helpful tips on the subject?

Answer (score 3):

GitWeb will categorize the repositories it lists, if—and only if—you enable the categorized output in the configuration section. You will need to change the value of [`$projects_list_group_categories`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/gitweb/gitweb.perl#L134) to make this happen:

```
our $projects_list_group_categories = 1;
```

Afterwards, GitWeb will pick up the category from the `gitweb.category` configuration in each repository. You can set this in Gitolite by setting the `category` for a `repo` to some value.

```
repo something
    RW+ = @members
    category = My category name
```

Comment: This was good, nice to see the categories in GitWeb, but the repositories are still shown in one long single list, which I still think is not the best. And I would like to be able to see this in GitList as well.

Comment: If you enable the category grouping as I said, GitWeb should group the repositories in separate lists by category. Yes, it’s still a single list with all repositories, but they are grouped by category. I guess this works similarly in GitList, but I have no idea how that works. I’m sure you can find something in its documentation.

Comment: I found the projects_list_group_categories variable at /usr/share/gitweb/gitweb.cgi

Comment: @Raddfood When you compile gitweb, the perl source is “compiled” to `gitweb.cgi` which then inlines all the configuration options.